# C# sorting date inside datagridview

Tags: sorting, date, datetime, datagridview

I need to sort dates inside a datagridview. I searched for answers but nothing seem to work on my case.

I use mysql database and the dates are stored as string like "31/12/2014".

i tried changing valuetype, defaultcellstyle and cell column format, but nothing worked.

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the string value or DateTime value? I suggest casting your value to DateTime, or do DateTime.Parse() before setting the cell value, the Data Grid handles the rest quite well as long as you set the cell with an object of the correct type.

Comment: thx for the input but i already solved the issue differently, just forgot to close the question. Btw i was storing as a string, but inside the program i declare as a datetime, then edited the cell format to appear as the text on the database.